# Why this sentence in SQL is working? COUNT and WHERE to get Students from Teachers

Tags: mysql, sql, count, where-clause

I tried to create a VIEW that merge some tables in order to have the "hottest" teacher in a educational platform.

First, I have a table with the users (some teachers, some students),
then in other I have the lessons created by the teachers,
finally, other one that has the relation between students and lesson.

when I use this SQL sentence

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `skn_teachers` AS 
select
`u`.`id_skn_users` AS `id_skn_users`,
`u`.`firstName` AS `firstName`,
`u`.`lastName` AS `lastName`,
COUNT(`ls`.`createdBy`) AS `countLessons`

from (`skn_users` AS `u`, `skn_rolesxusers` AS `rxu`, `skn_roles` AS `ro`, `skn_approved_lessons` AS `ls`)
where ((`rxu`.`id_skn_users` = `u`.`id_skn_users`) and (`rxu`.`id_skn_roles` = `ro`.`id_skn_roles`) and (`ro`.`name` = 'teacher') and (`ls`.`createdBy` = `rxu`.`id_skn_users`)) 
group by `u`.`id_skn_users`
```

the row countLessons show me the number of lessons per teacher eg.

```
id | firstName | lastName  | countLessons

1    Pepito       Perez                1
2    Julián       Figueroa             7
3    Daniel       Aguirre              2
```

which is correctly the number of lessons per teacher.

but I need the number of students that have the lessons created by each teacher (all of them, sum of all students in all lessons of THAT teacher), `countStudentsByTeacher`, in one of my attempts, get this SQl and it was a surprise when I got the number of students by teacher but I don't understand clearly what I did.

new SQL sentence:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `skn_teachers` AS 
select
`u`.`id_skn_users` AS `id_skn_users`,
`u`.`firstName` AS `firstName`,
`u`.`lastName` AS `lastName`,
COUNT(`ls`.`createdBy`) AS `countStudents`

from (`skn_users` AS `u`, `skn_rolesxusers` AS `rxu`, `skn_roles` AS `ro`, `skn_approved_lessons` AS `ls`, `skn_lessonsxusers` AS `lxu`)
where ((`rxu`.`id_skn_users` = `u`.`id_skn_users`) and (`rxu`.`id_skn_roles` = `ro`.`id_skn_roles`) and (`ro`.`name` = 'teacher') and (`ls`.`createdBy` = `rxu`.`id_skn_users`) and (`ls`.`id_skn_lessons` = `lxu`.`id_skn_lessons`)) 
group by `u`.`id_skn_users`
```

//

```
 id | firstName | lastName  | countLessons

    1    Pepito       Perez                10
    2    Julián       Figueroa             15
    3    Daniel       Aguirre              8
```

here, column `countLessons` shows really the number of students into all lessons created by each teacher, exactly what I wanted but I want to know why this works.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your 2nd query, you added at join to the table `skn_lessonsxusers`.  This causes the 2nd query to return additional rows per each student that was assigned the lesson.  The first query only returned the lessons that were created by each teacher.

Example:
Looking at the teacher "Daniel Aguirre", the underlying non-aggregated data for the first query might look like this:

```
id | firstName | lastName  | Lesson
3    Daniel       Aguirre       Math 101
3    Daniel       Aguirre       CS 104
```

So there are 2 lessons that he teaches.

Now if you add in the students for each lesson, i.e. the 2nd query, then the data might look like this.

```
id | firstName | lastName  | Lesson       |  Student
3    Daniel       Aguirre       Math 101       John
3    Daniel       Aguirre       Math 101       Bob
3    Daniel       Aguirre       Math 101       Sara
3    Daniel       Aguirre       Math 101       Mary
3    Daniel       Aguirre       CS 104         John
3    Daniel       Aguirre       CS 104         Bob
3    Daniel       Aguirre       CS 104         Dan
3    Daniel       Aguirre       CS 104         Sally
```

So now when you aggregate this 2nd set of data, it will show a count of 8 because there are 8 student/lesson combination for Daniel Aguirre.

Now assuming that John and Bob in the above 2nd data set are the same student, there are not really 8 different students taking lessons from Daniel Aguirre, there are 6 (John, Bob, Sara, Mary, Dan, and Sally).  If you wanted to show 6 in this example you would use:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT `lxu`.`student_id`) AS `countStudents`
```

where `student_id` is the column that represents a unique student in the `skn_lessonsxusers` table.  NOTE: your column is probably a different name than "student_id", but I don't know your table structure for this example so I just used "student_id".

Comment: thanks @BateTech, already tested without grouping and it worked as you said, now How would I get a another column with the ammount lesson per teacher?

Answer (score 0):

It works because you multiply each lesson by each student in this lesson

```
join...    'skn_approved_lessons' AS 'ls'

where...  and ('ls'.'createdBy' = 'rxu'.'id_skn_users')
```